# Import a .properties file into a java.util.Properties type variable in Configuration class via annotation

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-annotations

I am migrating my java application from spring to spring boot and along with it I want to **eradicate the xml based configuration** and move to **annotation based configuration** completely.

I want to load a properties file **as is** into a **java.util.Properties** type variable.

```
@Configuration
public class ApplicationConfig
{
  // inject the file into this variable
  private Properties myOtherProp;
}
```

In xml based configuration this was done in a line by:

```
<util:properties id="myOtherProp" location="classpath:myOtherProperties.properties"/>
```

and the way I am achieving this currently is by doing this:

```
@Configuration
public class ApplicationConfig
{
  private Properties myOtherProp;

  private void myMethodToInitialiseMyOtherProp()
  {
    myOtherProp = new Properties();
    myOtherProp.load(getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("myOtherProperties.properties"));
  }

  @Bean
  public myClass beanWhichUsesTheOtherProp()
  {
    myMethodToInitialiseMyOtherProp();
    return new myClass(myOtherProp);
  }
}
```

I am searching for a solution to do this in one line like how `@Value` does for primitive data types.
Or at least being able to call my method - myMethodToInitialiseMyOtherProp() where I declare the Properties variable so that I can remove the overhead of remembering to call the function to initialise the variable before using it for the first time anywhere.

I am aware of how to inject the individual fields declared inside myOtherProperties.properties but that is not what I am trying to achieve here. I wish to load the entire file into the variable - myOtherProp of type Properties.

Something like this:

```
@Configuration
public class ApplicationConfig
{
  // inject the file into this variable
  @Something-Like-Value-Annotation-To-Inject-The-File-In-One-Line
  // OR //
  @Some-Way-To-Call-myMethodToInitialiseMyOtherProp()
  private Properties myOtherProp;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You might want to refer to this. It would be helpful in you case.
Link: https://www.baeldung.com/properties-with-spring

Declare properties as:

```
@Configuration
@PropertySource("classpath:foo.properties")
public class PropertiesWithJavaConfig {
    //...
}
```

Use them in other clases as :
Example 1:

```
@Value( "${jdbc.url}" )
private String jdbcUrl;
```

Example 2:

```
@Autowired
private Environment env;
...
dataSource.setUrl(env.getProperty("jdbc.url"));
```

Note: Code snippets are from the link provided in answer.
Credits to Baeldung.

Comment: I have mentioned this in my question - "I am aware of how to inject the individual fields declared inside myOtherProperties.properties but that is not what I am trying to achieve here. I wish to load the entire file into the variable - myOtherProp of type Properties."

Comment: In Example 2, the entire properties file is getting loaded in it right?
Do you need the Properties myProperties only?
In case if there is no library dependency on the class type Properties, may be you can use the example 2 here.

Comment: In example 2 as well it is loading the properties file and accessing individual property declared inside it. That is not what I am trying to achieve as already stated in my description I want to load the entire file into a util.Properties variable.